# How to grep records which has a full stop in R

Tags: r

I am trying to grep all the records of a dataframe which has a full stop in it. But it returns all the records in the dataframe no matter it has a full stop or not.

```
dot=e[grep(".", e$e1),]
View(dot)
```

Can anyone help me to do this in the correct way please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use the fixed=True argument, or use "\."

```
dot=e[grep(".", e$e1, fixed=T),]
```

or

```
dot=e[grep("\\.", e$e1),]
```

The first option is probably preferable.

Comment: Thanks so much Imo